# Как узнать версию установленных компонентов в SDK Manager в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Как узнать версию установленных компонентов в SDK Manager в Android Studio? Там указывается только версия доступного обновления:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как узнать версию уже установленного компонента?

**P.S.** Да, можно зайти в папку sdk/build-tools/ и увидеть версию установленных Build-Tools, но можно ли как-то это увидеть из Android Studio, а не из файловой системы?

Comment: колонка Version на вашем скриншоте, это текущая версия

Comment: Нажмите на `Show package details` справа внизу

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо, не замечала раньше этого чекбокса. Опубликуйте как ответ)